# Convert if-else to concise list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Suppose there exists a string 'Hello World', and I wish to use a dictionary to get a mapping of elements and their frequencies, this following code does suffice, however if I need to use list comprehension, how can I use 'if', 'else'? Please provide your solutions

```
for i in s:
    if i in d:
        d[i]=d[i]+1
    else:
        d[i]=1
```

Comment: even more concise: use `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict(int)`

Comment: You are not building a list from your input elements. You are **counting** your elements. Use a `Counter()`.

Comment: I am looking at ways to convert it into list comprehension as well, please provide your solution for that. I can look at alternatives later

Comment: I dont understand why one has to downvote the question, it clearly says "How to implement a concise list comprehension", just give your thoughts on it and explain how to handle if -else conditions in list comprehension if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension (it doesn't make sense to use a list comprehension to build a dictionary):

```
s = 'Hello world'
d = {char: s.count(char) for char in set(s)}
```

The `set(s)` is a set of the unique characters in your string, and the comprehension creates a dictionary with the character as key and the number of occurences (using [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.count)) as value.

But you don't need to use a comprehension at all, python comes with "batteries included". In this case the battery is [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html):

```
import collections
collections.Counter(s)
```

---

In case you really want to use a list comprehension (my personal opinion: **you don't and shouldn't!**) you need to work with side-effects, for example:

```
s = 'Hello world'
d = {}
[d.__setitem__(i, d[i]+1) if i in d else d.__setitem__(i, 1) for i in s]
print(d)
```

The `__setitem__` calls are necessary because `d[i] = 1` or `d[i] = d[i] + 1` are assignments and therefore forbidden in comprehensions. But `__setitem__` is the functional alternative.

Comment: On point! Can you provide your view on handling if-else in list comprehension

Comment: @AshwinV I added an example of a list-comprehension with "if" and "else". It's the equivalent of your loop but is based on side-effects. It's fun as an intellectual exercise but normally you shouldn't do comprehensions just because of their side-effects.

Comment: Of course - a list-comp here is wrong on so many levels... So don't do it :)